# Removing a string return after a function has been processed

Tags: javascript, join, return

I'm a beginner and a student and I'm hoping someone can help me out.  I have an assignment where I need the program to be broken up into 3 functions.  The first takes a sentence from the user, the second converts the sentence into a new "pig language" depending on the length of each word, and the third displays the results in the console.  I have the heart of this program done, but I have a problem with clearing out the return string. Specifically, once the user has gone through all 3 steps, I don't want them to be able to enter into the 3rd part of the program and see the results again.  I want them to have to go back to the beginning.  Sorry for drawing this out so much, but I'm just not sure of how else to explain it.
Here's my code:

```
function prog1(){
var userLang = prompt("Type in your sentence");
//If the user enters an empty string
    if(userLang == ""){
        console.log("You must enter a sentence");
    }
//If the user presses cancel
    else if(userLang == null){
        wantToQuit = true;
    }
//If the user enters in a good string
    else {
        console.log("Thank you, now go to program 2");
        been2prog1 = true;
        return userLang;
    }
} 

function prog2(){
//sets newLang = userLang and splits the string
var newLang = prog1Lang.split(" ");

//enters loop to find length of each split word
var x = 0;
for( x = 0; x < newLang.length; x++ ){

//if it's 5 or less words, add -oink    
    if ((newLang[x].length) <= 5){
        newLang[x] += "-oink";
    }
//if it's more than 5 words, add -a
    else {
        newLang[x] += "-a";

    }       

}
**newLang.join(" ");**  

//put the string back together  

console.log("String converted");
been2prog2 = true;
return newLang;
}

 function prog3(){
var endLang = prog2Lang;
console.log(endLang);
**delete prog2Lang;**

}
```

I was thinking "delete" might work, as seen above, but I didn't do anything all all.  Then I was thinking a Boolean, but I am not sure how to go about doing so.  Any help would be much appreciated.

One last thing, I am also stuck on how to join my string back together.  Currently it logs it in the console as being a part of the array and separates each word with quotes and a comma.  I've looked up the .join(); and I thought it would do the trick, but it doesn't seem to work either.  I put it inside of the if else statements in function 2 but, it just freaks out when I do that, so pointers on this issue would also be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the newLang.join to itself..

```
newLang = newLang.join(" ");
```

Comment: Thanks!  Worked perfectly.  I would like to chalk this one up to my inexperience with the syntax.  Thanks again!

Comment: Happy to help. The Join method in javascript does not perform an opperation on the array transforming it into a concatenated string instead it returns an all new object that it creates from the array. So you could assign it to any variable. As you won't be needing the array anymore it is neat to assign it to it's self and the new sting object replaces the array.

Comment: Yep, makes perfect sense now that you've showed me.  I found myself getting lost after staring at all of it for about 10 hours now. :)

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure what the other bit was that you were having trouble with was, I was a bit confused.

if all you are trying to do is clear out a string variable then..

```
prog2Lang = null;

or 

prog2Lang = "";
```

null is a null object and "" is an empty string.

Is that what you were after?

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to clear the string after it goes through the 3rd function.  I put both of your examples above into the 3rd program and neither worked.

Comment: After it goes through the 3rd function, I don't want the user to be able to put 3 into the main menu again and get the same result, it should say something like you still need to enter a string.

Comment: Well the above should work. Maybe there is another problem with your code. In hte code above I don't actually see that anything is ever assigned to prog2Lang, this variable only seems to be used in prog3. Are you sure the variable you want to clear is called prog2Lang? The next thing to check is that the variable you want to clear is in the global scope. If it is in a different scope to where you are trying to clear it you may be clearing a different variable with the same name. Check those two and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Yeah, you were right.  I just didn't put it into the right part of my program (scope stuff).  I also needed it to clear program2's string which becomes a whole lot more complicated because I need that string to go into program 3. Ugh!  But yeah, it should be ok.  Prof only wanted it to clear after the 3rd program.  So yeah, hopefully it'll be ok.  Thanks again for your help!!!